# jQuery conditional select problems

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some problems with part of jQuery code in my form. Everything works fine except one part of code:

```
if ( $("#finish_day").val() > 4 ) {
    $('#start').attr('', '');
} else {
    $('#start, #end').not(this)
        .children('option[value=' + this.value + ']')
        .attr('selected', '')
        .siblings().attr('disabled', true);
}
```

Whole example you can test here: http://jsfiddle.net/amarcinkowski/k7kKV/3/

Here is the thing:

First problem: 
When I change the "Hour" field it automatically change me the "City" field, and after then I can't change the City. When i cut the above code the City field works fine.

Second problem:
I need to have all of "City1" options always active (now when I change the "Hour" I have one active option, and other disabled). The code above should work like this: When the value of "total day" field is less than (for example) 3 the value in "City2" field is the same as in "City1" field (City1: Katowice = City2: Katowice), and other options in City2 field are disabled.

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: First problem - fixed - the "value" in options was the same.

Answer (score 0):

I modify my code to:

```
if ( $("#finish_day").val() < 4 ) {
          $('#start, #end').not(this)
              .children('option[value=' + this.value + ']')
              .attr('selected', true)
              .siblings().attr('disabled', true);
} else {
    $('#end').attr('disabled', false);
}
```

It show the City1 option always active, and change value in City2 with the contition. I have one more problem - I don't know how to change the "else" section (when the value is greater then 3) to showing in City2 all the option value in active state?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand exactly what you want, but you may want to try this in your else statement:

```
$('#end option').attr('disabled', false);
```